# Problems trying to enable ASP.NET Core logging on 1&1 IONOS Windows Hosting

Tags: asp.net-core, logging, web-config, startup, ionos

I have created a simple ASP.NET Core 3.1 WebAPI project in Visual Studio 2022.

I want to log any errors. I have been following this post https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/31380.

First I added a webconfig.config to the project and added the following to enable logging:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="aspNetCore"/>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile="\LogFiles\stdout"></aspNetCore>  
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I then created a folder on my FTP server to store the LogFiles in the publish folder and set the write permissions to 644.

[image]

I have also added the following to the Program.cs class:

```
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
    {
        webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        webBuilder.CaptureStartupErrors(true)
        .UseSetting("detailedErrors", "true");
    });
```

I did edit the WebAPI.csproj file to enable the OutOfProcess hosting model to allow more than one project to run on separte subdomains.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>OutOfProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
</PropertyGroup>
```

When I access the API in the browser the log files are not created even if there is a startup error.

Does anyone have any experience of getting this working on 1&1 IONOS Windows Hosting packages?